# Как изменить аргумент плагина

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как изменить аргумент плагина с `one` на `two` при клике на кнопку `click`?

```js
one = {
  q: 1,
  w: 2,
  e: 3
}

two = {
  q: 4,
  w: 5,
  e: 6
};

(function($) {
  var pl1, binded = false;
  $.fn.player = function(pl) {
    pl1 = pl;

    if (binded) return;

    $('#q').on('click', function() {
      alert(pl1.q)
    });
    $('#w').on('click', function() {
      alert(pl1.w)
    });
    $('#e').on('click', function() {
      alert(pl1.e)
    });
    binded = true;
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().player(one);
  $('#r').on('click', function() {
    $().player(two);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="q">1</button>
  <button id="w">2</button>
  <button id="e">3</button>
  <button id="r">click</button>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tajaj/1/

Answer (score 1):

```js
one = {
  q: 1,
  w: 2,
  e: 3
}

two = {
  q: 4,
  w: 5,
  e: 6
};

(function($) {
  var pl1, binded = false;
  $.fn.player = function(pl) {
    pl1 = pl;

    if (binded) return;

    $('#q').on('click', function() {
      alert(pl1.q)
    });
    $('#w').on('click', function() {
      alert(pl1.w)
    });
    $('#e').on('click', function() {
      alert(pl1.e)
    });
    binded = true;
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().player(one);
  $('#r').on('click', function() {
    $().player(two);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="q">1</button>
  <button id="w">2</button>
  <button id="e">3</button>
  <button id="r">click</button>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tajaj/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CJQT7/1/

Помогите с этим примером пожалуйста. При первом вызове весь плагин работает, а при втором binded = true и код не работает